# JQuery collapsable Panel

Tags: jquery

How does the Jquery use to create similar to Ajax CollapsiblePanel?

Comment: are you looking for some container that gets its info from ajax and expands the element according to the contents returned?

Answer (score 1):

**Manually:**
Have a div for the header (which will be clicked to expand and collapse), and another div for the content (which will have the matter to be displayed).

here's an example.

```
//To Show
$('#myheader1').click(function(){$('#mycontent1').Show())};

//To Show
$('#myheader1').click(function(){$('#mycontent1').Hide())};
```

You'll have to maintain the visibility status in a variable.

**Ready control**

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/accordion

Comment: +1, you can also use `Toggle()` (http://docs.jquery.com/Events/toggle) to avoid having to store any visibility state.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <span class="title">Show/Hide</span>
    <div>
       <!-- put some elements here... -->
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

---

```
$(".title").click(function() { $(this).next("div").slideToggle("slow"); });
```